# Find the number of homomorphisms from $Z_m$ to $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

The kernel of the homomorphism will be a normal subgroup and the normal subgroups of $Z_m$ are of the form $\langle\frac{m}{d}\rangle$ where $d|m$.I can find out for particular cases but how do I generalize this? Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: Yes even that is what I think but this was given as a homework problem so is there any non trivial homomorphism which is common to all?

Comment: The number of homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}_m\rightarrow S_n$ equals the number of elements in $S_n$ whose order divides $m$. Not sure if there is a nice way of counting those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Thorgott says, this is the number of permutations in $S_n$ of order dividing $m$. Equivalently this is the number of permutations whose cycles have length dividing $m$. There isn't a particularly simple closed form for these, but if we let $a_m(n)$ denote the number of such permutations then there is an exponential generating function

$$\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{a_m(n)}{n!} t^n = \exp \left( \sum_{k \mid m} \frac{t^k}{k} \right).$$

This follows from a general result that I think is called the "exponential formula in permutation form" and unfortunately I don't know a really elementary discussion of it but see, for example, [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/24/gila-vi-the-cycle-index-polynomials-of-the-symmetric-groups/) or (more advanced) [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/04/the-categorical-exponential-formula/) or the first few chapters of Flajolet and Sedgewick's *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html)* about techniques for writing down generating functions.

For example, when $m = 2$ we get

$$\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{a_2(n)}{n!} t^n = \exp \left( t + \frac{t^2}{2} \right)$$

which gives the generating function of the [involution numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_(mathematics)), counting the number of involutions (permutations of order dividing $2$) in $S_n$. Already this simple case doesn't have a nice closed form but this generating function allows at least a precise description of the asymptotics.

Were you really given this problem as homework? It would make more sense to me if $m$ and $n$ were fixed small integers in your homework. Then you can just do casework on the possible cycle decompositions.